# Copy-Item on registry + exclude

Tags: powershell, registry, copy-item

I am having slight difficulties to copy an entire key with its contents due to REG_NONE value type not being supported by PS 2.0.

```
$key = "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook"
```

There is a need to copy its entire contents to a different location in the HKCU hive eg: $key2 = "HKCU:\Backup"

So basically it should be as simple as:

```
Copy-Item -Path $key -Destination $key2 -Force -Recurse
```

However null value error occurs when PS tries to copy this part:

```
HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\AutoDiscover
```

Im stuck on excluding this particular part of the key from copy-item.

```
Copy-Item -Path $key -Destination $key2 -Exclude "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook\AutoDiscover" -Force -Recurse
```

Any good soul could give me a hint how to do that:) ? Im searching for examples but w/o success atm.

Ps. Sorry for not so clean text. Written from mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that Copy-Item can't handle binary values with a null value, this has been resolved in Version 3.

A method to skip over and log any key that could not be copied could be this:

```
$Key1 = 'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Outlook'
$Key2 = 'HKCU:\Backup'

# IF Key2 doesnt exist, create it
if(-Not (Test-Path -Path $Key2)) {
    New-Item -ItemType Key -Path $Key2
}

# Get references
$SourceKey = Get-Item -Path $Key1
$TargetKey = Get-Item -Path $Key2

# List all key recursively
$FailedKeys = @(Get-ChildItem -Path $Key1 -Recurse | Foreach-Object {
    # Store sourcepath
    $Source = $_.PSPath
    # Determine target path
    $Destination = $_.PSPath.Replace($SourceKey.PSPath, $TargetKey.PSPath)
    Try
    {
        # Try to copy
        Copy-Item -Path $_.PSPath -Destination $Destination -ErrorAction Stop
    }
    Catch
    {
        # If copy fails, output the sourcepath
        Write-Output $Source
    }
})

if($FailedKeys.Count -gt 0) {
    Write-Warning -Message 'Failed to copy the following keys:'
    $FailedKeys
}
```

Comment: Simon, thank you for the effort you've put into it :) it's far more what i expected!